# Jersey REST: Can I map @PathParam from field of argument

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a RESTful interface that does CRUD on some object:

```
class Foo {
   String id;
   ...
}
```

The declaration for an update looks like:

```
public class FooCRUD {
   @PUT
   @Path("/foos/{id}")
   public void replace(@PathParam("id") id, Foo foo){...}
}
```

But `Foo` already contains the `id`.  I'd like to do the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
class Foo {
   @PathParam("id")
   String id;
   ...
}
public class FooCRUD {
   @PUT
   @Path("/foos/{id}")
   public void update(Foo foo){...}
}
```

Is there some way to avoid adding the extra parameter to the method?

Comment: The id in Foo class will be sent with the request? or it's empty?

Comment: Foo will contain a valid id field.

Comment: So I think there is no need for id in the Path Param, you just get it from the body with foo object.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to combine a message-based and RESTful system.  REST conventions want the entity ID in the URL path.  But with a message-broker there's no URL path, so it needs to go in the message.  Would make standing up a web service gateway to front a message-based server easier because the bodies and method signatures would be unchanged.  So I would like the client proxy to automatically pull the ID out of the body parameter and use it to build the URL path, and have the server pull the ID out of the URL path and put it in the body.  I'm lazy and don't want to write that code.